# Pig Schema - Tuple with unknown size but known datatype

Tags: apache-pig

For a tuple that will look like this
("Apples", "Bananas", "Guavas", ....)

in which the number of values in the tuple is not fixed, but the datatype is always a string.

How do i specify the `org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema` of this tuple?
i.e what do i specify instead of the `null` in the code below.

```
Schema.FieldSchema fruits = new Schema.FieldSchema("fruits", null, TUPLE);
```

Or maybe another way?